# Is there a way to prevent loading of images in a jQuery objectified HTML fragment

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a HTML fragment that I'm objectifying via jQuery for the purpose of extracting some data from it. This fragment has some image resources that I don't want the browser to download. Is there a way to do it.

A simplified version of my current code:

```
var html = '<p class="data">Blah Blah</p>...<img src="/a/b/...png">...<div>...</div>';

var obj = $(html); // this makes the browser download the contained images as well!!!

var myData = {
    item_1: obj.find('.data:first').text(),
    item_2: obj.find('.data2:first').text(),
    .... // and so on..
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you think there will be instances of the substring `src=` in the string that matter to you, you could do:

```
html = html.replace(/src=/g, "data-src=");
```

or possibly

```
html = html.replace(/src\s*=/g, "data-src=");
```

...to allow for whitespace. That way, the browser won't see the `src` attribute, and won't trigger the download.

Sometimes the direct approach is best. Of course, if you think there may be `src=` substrings that will matter in terms of what you're trying to extract, then...

Comment: Thank you. Don't think i'll have `src=` anywhere in the data i need extracted. This should work. (can't believe i couldn't think of this!)

Comment: This answer sounds familiar. Hmmm [ah yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302129/construct-a-dom-tree-from-a-string-without-loading-resources-specifically-image/2302157#2302157) ;)

Comment: @CrescentFresh: OMG! Well, at least I'm consistent.